# How to not open multiple windows in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, button, dialog

In my WPF application I use this code to open a new windows from a button:

```
private void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoginDialog dialog = new LoginDialog();
    dialog.Show();    
}
```

But when there is already a LoginDialog open and I click the LoginBtn again it open a new LoginDialog windows. How do I code it so it override the previous one that is open, if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a local variable of type Login dialog and check if its null

```
LoginDialog _dialog;

private void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(_dialog == null)
    {
        _dialog = new LoginDialog();
     }
    _dialog.Show();    
}
```

Comment: small change: '=' to '=='

Answer (score 3):

```
private void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoginDialog _dialog = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<LoginDialog>().FirstOrDefault() ?? new LoginDialog();
    _dialog.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ShowDialog()` instead of `Show()` to make the dialog modal (so that you cannot do anything else while the dialog is open).

That also allows you to get the return value, indicating whether the user (i.e.) pressed cancel or ok.

Comment: Hi @PMF. I already think of that solution, but I have to be able to use my main windows when this window is open.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be able to use this due to design restrictions however you could open the new window so that it disables the others.

```
private void LoginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoginDialog dialog = new LoginDialog();
    dialog.ShowDialog();    
}
```

Comment: Exactly, hence I mentioned it may not be able to be used due to design restrictions however I don't know what he wants his program to do...

Comment: well if he wants to click again he definitely wants access isn't ?

Comment: He didn't say that, but he said currently that is a possibility

Comment: Hi guys thanks for your respons, but I need to be able to use my main window when this current window is open.

Comment: see op's comment to PMF's ans, he suggested same thing

Comment: Ah well in that case @Muds solution is the best.