# Restrict opening of duplicate dialog

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF Parent Child application, Parent window is ribbon window, on click of RibbonButton, Child window will be opened.

To open window code is:

```
MyWindow uiObj=new MyWindow();
ShowWindow(uiObj, this);
```

I have written this function since this will be in seperate dll and it should not be specific to any particular UI

```
public void ShowWindow(Object Obj, Object ObjThis)
{
    Window winObj = (Window)Obj;
    winObj.Owner = (Window)ObjThis;
    winObj.ShowInTaskbar = false;
    winObj.Show();            
}
```

**WHAT I NEED:**
Whenever the same button is clicked, I want to check whether the window is opened or not and then open.

I cannot declare my UI class as

```
MyWindow uiObj;
```

or

```
MyWindow uiObj = null;
```

and pass to my function

```
ShowWindow(uiObj, this);
```

So the window object will be passed after making "new" and checks like "null" dint work

I believe there would be better solution.

Comment: Do you need to use your parent window as long as the child window is opened? Or can you just block it?

Comment: heve a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33263605/how-to-not-open-multiple-windows-in-wpf/33263614?noredirect=1#comment54328955_33263614)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can catch events: Closing/Shown:

```
MyWindow uiObj=new MyWindow();
uiObj.Closing+={windowsOpened = false;}
uiObj.Shown+={windowsOpened = true;}
public void ShowWindow(Object Obj, Object ObjThis)
{ 
if(windowsOpened)return;
...
```